# Campo requerido si el valor de otro campo está en un array

Tags: javascript, php, html, validación

Tengo este trozo código de html:

```html
<div class="row row-cols-1">
  <label for="permissionsSelect">Por el siguiente motivo:</label>
  <br>
  <div class="input-group">
    <select
      class="form-select mb-3"
      aria-label=".form-select-lg example"
      id="permissionsSelect"
      name="permissionsSelect"
      onchange="showHiddenFields()"
    >
      @foreach(config('proofMissingTeacherSelectOptions') as $key => $value)
        <option value="{{ $value }}" id="{{ $key }}">
          {{ $value }}
        </option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
  @if($errors->get('permissionsSelect'))
    <div class="text-danger mb-3 mt-0">
      {{ $errors->get('permissionsSelect')[0] }}
    </div>
  @endif
  <div class="col mb-4" id="medicalProof" style="display: none;">
    <div>
      <input
        type="radio"
        onchange="hideAnotherReason()"
        id="doctor"
        name="reason"
        value="el médico no tiene consulta en otro horario."
      />
      <label for="doctor" class="radio-label">El médico no tiene consulta en otro horario</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input
        type="radio"
        onchange="hideAnotherReason()"
        id="schedule"
        name="reason"
        value="la necesidad de asistencia ha impedido hacerlo en otro horario o en otra fecha."
      />
      <label for="schedule" class="radio-label">La necesidad de asistencia ha impedido hacerlo en otro horario o en otra fecha</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input
        type="radio"
        onchange="displayAnotherReason()"
        name="reason"
        id="another"
        value="another"
      />
      <label for="another" class="radio-label">Otro motivo:</label>
    </div>
    <input
      type="text"
      onchange="updateAnotherValue()"
      style="display: none"
      id="anotherReason"
      class="form-control"
      name="anotherReason"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

Y este sería el javascript:

```js
function showHiddenFields() {
  const permissionsSelect = document.querySelector('#permissionsSelect');
  const selectedOption = permissionsSelect.options[permissionsSelect.selectedIndex].id;
  const medicalProof = document.querySelector('#medicalProof');
  if (selectedOption === 'L2' || selectedOption === 'P14') {
    medicalProof.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    medicalProof.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Anotaciones:

- `proofMissingTeacherSelectOptions` es un archivo de la carpeta `config` con un array con todos los valores que puede tomar el `select`.
- Y tengo otro archivo en la carpeta `config` llamado `specialMedicalReason` con un array que tiene 2 valores que si se seleccionan se habilitan los `radiobuttons`

Necesito una regla de validación de Laravel que haga que esos campos son requeridos si el campo de tipo `select` tiene uno de los valores de `specialMedicalReason`.

Este es el array de specialMedicalReason.

```js
return [
  'L2: Ausencia por enfermedad no superior a tres días. (10)',
  'P14: Permiso de ausencia del trabajo para la conciliación de la vida familiar y profesional. (8)',
];
```